# Expressing Sub-sequences of a sequence - notation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, notation

Given a sequence $b_n = \sin(\frac{n \pi}{2})$, I am trying to show that $(b_n)$ diverges.

I have the idea down, I know exactly what to do, but just not HOW to do it.

I know that any convergent sequence, has all sub-sequences converging to the same limit.

So all I need to do is show two sub-sequences which converge to different points.

This is easy, but I am not sure how to express it.

I want to use the notation that a sub-sequence of $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is $(b_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$

how can I express the sub-sequences of $\{1, 1, 1, \dots\}$ and $\{0, 0, 0, \dots\}$ ?

The former occurs for every 4th value of $n$ beginning from $n=1$ and the latter from every 2nd value of $n$ beginning from $n=2$.

Could I write the former as the sub-sequence $(b_{4n+1})$ and the latter as $(b_{2n})$? would this be correct notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

an even integer is of the form $n=2k$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$, an odd integer has the form $n=2k+1$; for $k$ odd or even your $sin$ function change sign, so you have also to separate the two  case for $k$ (in the same manner)
.

Comment: I'm just curious as to how one would express these cases in $(b_{n_k})$ form

Comment: $n_k= 2k$ or $n_k= 4k+1$ or $n_k= 4k+3$ .